# Not able to post questions in Stack Overflow [solution found: remove access restrictions to blocked js files]

Tags: support

I have not been able to ask any questions in Stack Overflow for the past few weeks. For the record I am not even getting any alerts like:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

My issue was that nothing was happening when I clicked Post button.

Comment: do you have any deleted questions which are downvoted?

Comment: Hi suraj thank you for your response. I might have possibly found the solution. The problem was that access to one of the js files used in stackoverflow was blocked in my organization. Thankyou very much for your help. I have been trying to resolve this issue for many days. But couldnt find the solution until today after posting here.

Comment: You should clarify that in the question by [editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/349699/edit) it. I was assuming a possible question ban given the context.

Comment: @Suraj. Sorry suraj. I apologize for creating confusion. I was confused myself because I was earlier able to ask questions and this happened all of a sudden when I was no longer able to post any questions. I have edited my question and will post the possible solution as similar issues could happen anywhere all because of the restricted access to js files.

Comment: no issues.. I retracted my close vote. Looks like a different problem

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to everyone who helped me in solving this issue.

The problem was not at all related to downvotes. The problem was that the access to some of Stack Overflow's js files had been blocked by our network admin due to some security reason (I don't know why).

If anyone else is facing the same issue kindly contact your admin to check whether they have blocked access to js files used by Stack Overflow.